# WPF control for treemap visualization with nesting levels

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, treemap

I'm looking for a WPF control for treemap visualization like this:
[image]

Key point here for me - constant height and variable width (or vice versa). It differs from popular visualization style when we devide a rectangle on rectangular regions (with areas proportional to values of some attribute, e.g. file size).
I'm aware of Silverlight/WPF toolkit' treemap and treemap.codeplex.com. And also Teleric's xamTreeMap. But all of them visualize only leaf nodes not whole tree with all nesting levels - this' what I need.